# How to write a sentence with two genitives describing one noun

Tags: grammar-choice, syntax, genitive

I would like to translate the following sentence into Latin.

> Minerva is the goddess of wisdom and of wool.

My first guess would be,

> *Minerva est dea sapientiae et lanae.*

But I'm not sure whether this is the correct syntax. Is the use of two genitives modifying one noun, *dea*, correct? Also, could the word order be improved?

Comment: Regarding word order, the answer to this question may be helpful: [What word order resolves the ambiguity of two nominative nouns in a sentence?](http://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/669/what-word-order-resolves-the-ambiguity-of-two-nominative-nouns-in-a-sentence) It supports my intuition that "esse" normally comes after the complement in a sentence of this structure.

Comment: "Minerva dea sapientiae et lanae est" would be better

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your syntax is correct.
You can combine as many genitives as you wish in a similar fashion.
For choosing between *et* and *-que*, see [the question about that choice](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/1/79).
I think *et* is more appropriate here.

To improve your translation, I would put *est* all the way at the end: *Minerva dea sapientiae et lanae est.*
Besides being more natural word order in Latin, it helps to group the genitives together.
If you want to keep *est* closer to *dea*, *dea est* is more natural than *est dea*.
If you put *est* between the genitives, wool becomes a side note:
*Minerva dea sapientiae est et lanae.*
"Minerva is the goddess of wisdom, and also of wool."

Comment: I made a small edit, which I'll mention because I know correct English is important to you. You "put" *est* "at" the end, while you "move" it "to" the end (just as you can "move" something "from" somewhere but you can't "put" something "from" somewhere).

Comment: @JoelDerfner, thanks! Things like this are always a source of confusion, especially since in Finnish things are different.

Comment: How about _Minerva sapientiae et lanae est dea_?

Comment: @BenKovitz, that is also possible. I have a feeling that that word order is somewhat less idiomatic than *Minerva dea sapientiae et lanae est*. My gut feeling has failed me before in Latin word order, though.