# Where is the correct position to set right or left of muscle names for anatomical names?

Tags: grammar-choice, syntax, grammar-identification, anatomia

Muscles and bones have Latin names as can be found on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_skeletal_muscles_of_the_human_body).

I need to name muscles and bones with their Latin name and I also need to specify if it's the left or the right muscle in the human body.

Where is the correct position for the Latin words for left (sinistra) and right (dextra) for a muscle or bone name?

Is there a general rule where to position this word?

Does the form of the left and right also depend on the case?

**Example**

The [`musculus latissimus dorsi`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latissimus_dorsi_muscle) exists on the humans back on the left and right side.

What is the correct naming if I explicitly want to point to the left muscle?

1. `musculus latissimus dorsi sinistra`
2. `musculus latissimus sinistra dorsi`
3. `musculus sinistra latissimus dorsi`
4. `sinistra musculus latissimus dorsi`

**Edit**

Since I also need the plural forms of left and right in Latin for muscles which are described as groups I think I need to use those:

Singular

- sinister sinistra sinistrum
- dexter dextra dextrum

Plural

- sinistrī sinistrae sinistra
- dextrī dextrae dextra

Source: [Wikipedia sinister](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sinister), [Wikipedia dexter](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dexter)

Comment: Welcome to the site and thanks for the nice question! One option worth considering is replacing *dexter* (right) with *lateris dextri* (of the right side). I faintly recall seeing that, but I don't know what would be a canonical choice in an anatomical context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Where is the correct position for the Latin words for left and right for a muscle or bone name and is there a general rule where to position this word?**

In modern (English) usage, the Latin for left and right is not commonly used.  Nevertheless, I think we can deduce a general rule by (1) looking at early anatomy books and (2) extrapolating from the use of other adjectives in anatomical works, both early and modern.

Thus, in [Vesalius](http://www.vesaliusfabrica.com/en/new-fabrica/art-of-the-new-fabrica/sample-pages.html#page/3) (1514-1564), we see the following examples:

> *ramus **dexter*** and *ramus **sinister*** [masc. sing. nom.]
>
> *vena gastroomentalis **dextra*** and *vena gastroomentalis **sinistra*** [fem. sing. nom.]
>
> *ostium atrioventriculare **dextrum*** [neut. sing. nom]

From this, I think we can deduce that (a) the case, number, and gender of *dexter* and *sinister* agrees with the anatomical part under consideration (in these examples, *ramus*, *vena*, and *ostium* respectively); (b) the case is always in the nominative; and (c) *dexter* and *sinister* comes at the end.

If we look at other adjectives, we can see the same pattern.  Again, in Vesalius:

> *vena mesenterica **superior*** and *vena mesenterica **inferior***
>
> *venae gastricae **breves***
>
> *aorta carotis **interna***

References to muscles follow the same pattern; for example:

> *musculus flexor pollicis **brevis*** and *musculus abductor pollicis **longus***

This pattern is still used in modern editions of anatomy books (I have used Moore & Dalley, 4th ed., *Clinically Oriented Anatomy* and Williams, Warwick, Dyson & Bannister, *Gray's Anatomy*, 37th ed.):

> *abductor pollicis **longus*** and *extensor pollicis **brevis***
>
> *gluteus **medius***
>
> *obturator **internus***
>
> *adductor **magnus***

So far, we can see a pattern like this:

- a muscle/vein/bone etc. in the nominative case
- *plus* the part of the body to which it belongs (typically in the genitive)
- *plus* an adjective describing its location/position, especially when relative to another similar structure and/or an imagined mid-line of
  the body (inferior and superior; internal and external; right and
  left), in the nominative case, agreeing with the first part

Your particular question contains a superlative (*latissimus)* which none of my examples include.  However, I think we can make a case for it to stay with *musculus* as it describes the muscle, rather than locates it, in the same way *abductor* or *flexor* does in the examples above.  Thus, I would write:

> *musculus latissimus dorsi sinister*
>
> "the widest muscle [masc. sing. nom.] of the back [gen.] left side
> [specifying location, masc. sing. nom. agreeing with *musculus
> latissimus* "

ADDIT: if you have more than one adjective giving location, it seems both should go at the end but *dexter* and *sinister* still always seem to be last, as in the following examples (from Vesalius):

> *arteria carotis **interna dextra***
>
> *nervus laryngeus **recurrens dexter***

Comment: If I understand you correct then I should always use the nominative form and put it at the end. Depending on the muscle(s) I should use `dexter`, `dextra`, `dextrum` or `sinister`, `sinistra`, `sinistrum`.
What are the plural forms of those words?

Comment: @BrunoBieri _dextri_, _dextrae_, _dextra_ and _sinistri_, _sinistrae_, _sinistra_ respectively.  However, given that _musculus_ is masculine (_musculi_ in the plural), you may only need to ever use _dexter/dextri_ and _sinister/sinistri_

Comment: @BrunoBieri  Although, I note that your original question mentions bones, in which case _os_ is neuter so you will use _dextrum/dextra_ and _sinistrum/sinistra_

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I thought so as well but I came accross: `platysma` which I think is female.

Comment: @BrunoBieri  Ah, I see.  It does look feminine - I suspect it is Greek in origin, from πλατύς/platus, meaning wide, spread over a large area, so that may complicate matters ... EDIT In fact, πλάτυσμα is a Greek word (a flat object) and is neuter in Greek.

Answer (score 4):

It seems usage of Latin name for muscles many times does not specify the side of the body **in Latin**. Instead, they use English (or other languages), e.g. "left/right *latissimus dorsi*" (e.g. left [here](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=es&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=left+latissimus+dorsi+&btnG=)). However, the Latin for right and left are still used in some cases. Most of the cases I could find (without attempting to provide an exhaustive statistical analysis) seem to use the nominative case ("the right muscle X"), with a few using the genitive form ("the muscle X of the right").

For example, from this book:

[image: photo of book page showing the following muscle names: Nodi lymphoidei colici dextri, Nodi lymphoidei colici medii, Nodi lymphoidei colici sinistri]

(*[Atlas of Human Anatomy: Latin Terminology, 7th edition](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=du1qDwAAQBAJ&lpg=RA1-PA16&ots=ArIc-60IWX&dq=dextri%20latissimus%20dorsi&pg=RA1-PA18#v=onepage&q&f=false),* by Frank H. Netter)

The above uses the nominative (as cnread noted, these are in plural).

Other examples are in this book, which lists some body parts and in parenthesis has *Dextri et Sinistri* (also plural) (*[Normal Lymph Node Topography](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-642-58193-9),* by Eckart Richter and Thomas Feyerabend).

Examples with singular use of nominative (dexter) can be seen [here](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=es&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=ductus+lymphaticus+dexter&btnG=) and [here](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=es&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=ductus+lymphaticus+sinister&btnG=).

This nominative case is also suggested in the Wikipedia entry about [anatomical terms of location](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anatomical_terms_of_location).

Finally, regarding the order of words, [in Latin this is sometimes irrelevant](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/5377/word-order-in-latin). Still, if you want to follow some of the medical uses referred above, a common choice seems to be

> musculus latissimus dorsi sinister

(i.e the side at the end). In any case, I would not advice to use *musculus latissimus sinistri dorsi*, since you are breaking the muscle name apart [pun intended].

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Are you aware if there is a rule when to only use the `sinistri` part and when to use `lateris sinistri` as stated in the comment from Joonas?

Comment: @BrunoBieri see update.

Comment: Are you sure dextri and sinistri (and medii) are genitive in the examples you give? If I saw those phrases, I would assume the adjectives were nominative, agreeing with nodi, so that the phrase for the original question would be musculus latissimus dorsi sinister.

Comment: @cnread What do you mean "agreeing with nodi"? I provided a link to examples using the nominative. In the end, the issue is whether you want to say "right muscle" or "muscle of the right". Both seem correct to me.

Comment: @luchonacho The examples in your picture are all plurals. The half-visible *faciales* also points at this. There does not seem to be an implicit *lateris* as far as I can tell, unless there are examples that make it unambiguous.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta oh, I see now! Sure, they are plural, suggesting nominative. It remains the case that both nominative and genitive are used, and I showed links with both cases.

Comment: @BrunoBieri Notice there was an error in my previous (accepted) answer (noted by cnread and joonas). I've corrected it.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Updated the answer