# How do I name the individual parts of the lumbricals muscle of the foot in latin?

Tags: grammar-choice, syntax, grammar-identification, anatomia

As we can see, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lumbricals_of_the_foot) lists the lumbricals muscle and tells us that the muscle contains four parts.

I need to name all four individual parts of the muscle and their respective side in the body. I already asked a [similar question here](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/11424).

Again I looked up the English words `first`, `second`, `third` and `fourth` in Latin and found those words:

1. primis
2. secundus
3. tertium
4. quartus

How do I name muscles or bones which have a numeration in their name as the `lumbricals` muscle?

And are the Latin word for first, second, third and fourth used correct here?

My attempt is to just add the numeration at the end of the name:

> *musculus lumbricalis pedis primis sinister* --> first lumbrical muscle of the left foot

**EDIT**

I'm looking for the first twelve ordinal numbers. According to the [provided wikipedia](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Latin_ordinal_numbers) link they are:

1. primus
2. secundus
3. tertius
4. quartus
5. quintus
6. sextus
7. septimus
8. octavus
9. nonus
10. decimus
11. undecimus
12. duodecimus

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Other muscles with several enumerated parts seem to use *primus, secundus, tertius, ...*, this is, the **masculine** nominative of [ordinal numbers](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Latin_ordinal_numbers) (masculine because *musculus* is masculine). This is consistent with the answers in your other question.

Examples of such use are:

- *[extensor pollicis](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Fn9IAAAAYAAJ&lpg=PA333&ots=nC-9giu_Bv&dq=extensor%20primus%20pollicis&pg=PA333#v=onepage&q=extensor%20primus%20pollicis&f=false)*
- [*adductor*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=4zYAAAAAQAAJ&dq=primus%20secundus%20tertius%20muscle%20anatomy&pg=PA343#v=onepage&q=primus%20secundus%20tertius%20muscle%20anatomy&f=false)
- *trochanter*:

[image]

- *peronaeus*

(the latter two taken from [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=loE_AAAAYAAJ&q=Practical+Anatomy+of+the+Rabbit:+An+Elementary+Laboratory+Textbook+in+Mammalian+Anatomy&dq=Practical+Anatomy+of+the+Rabbit:+An+Elementary+Laboratory+Textbook+in+Mammalian+Anatomy&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi9lYG_67TkAhWBoFwKHZwkCVsQ6AEIMDAB))

Given this, the answer to your question is just to add the nominative to the phrase. Recall word order is not so relevant. Some references above have the number in the middle, with others at the end.

PS: your list of Latin numbers is odd, since it includes different cases and genders. *Secundus* and *quartus* are nominative masculine (as in the suggested solution). However, *primis* is dative or ablative (and any gender) whereas *tertium* is nominative neuter (instead of masculine). You want to use a consistent case and gender.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much. I'm looking for the names from `first` to `twelfth` to name also the rips. I'll check your link to wikipedia to the ordinal numbers.