# New to Latin—why is the Present Indicative sometimes at the end, and sometimes in the middle of a sentence?

Tags: grammar-choice, lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata, word-order

I'm working my way through Lingua Latina Per Se Illustrata, and I've come across something that's tripping me up when I try to write.

Example: Gallia *est* in Europa (pardon the lack of accents); and Arabia quoque in Asia *est*.

Why is "est" sometimes in the middle of the sentence, and sometimes at the end? The same goes for "sunt."

Comment: Welcome to the site, Sermo! I took the liberty of adding a few tags, assuming that you meant *Lingua Latina Per Se Illustrata*. If you meant something else, please edit the question and accept my apologies.

Comment: I did mean that! Apologies, I thought I could be shortened, I didn't really think about whether or not similar titles exist.

Comment: As *Lingua Latina* just means "the Latin Language", I'm sure it can be misunderstood. I had no specific title in mind; I just wanted to be sure. Misunderstanding things online is all too easy... Anyway, feel free to make any further edits if you feel like it.

Comment: Related question with relevant answers: [What word order resolves the ambiguity of two nominative nouns in a sentence?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/669/what-word-order-resolves-the-ambiguity-of-two-nominative-nouns-in-a-sentence)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Latin word order is very free, and the predicate — like *est* or *sunt* — can go anywhere.
Any of these is valid:

- *Gallia est in Europa.*
- *Gallia in Europa est.*
- *Est Gallia in Europa.*
- *Est in Europa Gallia.*
- *In Europa Gallia est.*
- *In Europa est Gallia.*

The most common choice is *Gallia in Europa est* (and SOV in general), but the rule — if any — is not to stick to any order but to have variations across any text.
An unusual word order can also be used for emphasis.
I would say that the largest emphasis in a Latin sentence is on the first word and the second largest one on the last word.

Comment: That's unbelievably nice to hear. I was wondering why the author didn't try to make it clearer why he had chosen to move the word order. I was fearing that it would be a complicated, heavily contextual rule.

Appreciate the answer and peace of mind!

Comment: @Sermo I'm glad I could bring you some peace of mind! If you have any more questions about that book or Latin in general, I would much like to see them on this site.